# website is not accessible with domain name

Tags: java, web-hosting, tomcat8

My website is not accessible with domain name refer below tomcat settings
I am able to access website using www.abc.com/abc but not directly www.abc.com
Kindly hlep me to setup this. below is my configuration in server.xml 
I am using tomcat8

```
<Host name="abc.com" appBase="/usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/abc">
  <Alias>www.abc.com</Alias>
  <Context path="/abc" reloadable="true" privileged="true" 
 docBase="/usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/abc" debug ="1"/>
<!--
 <Context path="/manager" debug="0" 
 docBase="/usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/manager">
 </Context>
 -->
</Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove /abc from the path attribute of your app's context, leave it empty, just so: path=""

Comment: But now ajax is not working and due to this other url on landing page are not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

i think the `<Context path="/abc"` should be `<Context path="/"`

Comment: Please use the vote options if this was the right answer  :) Thanks

Comment: But now ajax is not working and due to this other url on landing page are not accessible

Comment: Check all your references in your scripts to paths. They should not include /abc